# Enquiry system profile

Tags: mongodb

we are tyring to enquiry system.profile to collect all operation that impacts some document (ie DATA.COD:12)

This is a snippet of a system.profile document.

```
{
        op:"update",
        ns:"db.myCollection",
        command:{
                q: {
                "DATA.COD":12,
                NAME:"PIPPO"
        },
        u:{
                FIELD:"PLUTO"},
        ...
}
```

We'd like something like this

```
{op:"update", "command.q.DATA.COD":{"$exists":true},ns:"db.myCollection"}
```

but the field inside the name doesn't work (it search a subdocument). we have already tried with escape but nothing so far...

Comment: The mongo query language uses the dot as a field separator.  While you can store documents with dots in the field names, https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/limits/#mongodb-limits-and-thresholds mentions that this causes problems when querying.

Comment: It's clear but system.profile is a technical collection provided by out if the box capability..

Comment: system.profile is a collection name, you can use `getCollection("system.profile")` for that, the problem you are encountering is the field name "DATA.COD" has a dot in it and the query language is interpreting `"command.q.DATA.COD"`to look for a field named 'COD' inside a document in a field named 'DATA'.

Comment: i know but i'm not able to solve it

Answer (score 0):

This is not very pretty, and likely not very efficient, but you should be able to get an equivalent match using `$expr` and some aggregation ops:

```
db.system.profile.find({op:"update",$expr:{$gt:[{$size:{$filter:{input:{$objectToArray:"$$ROOT.command.q"},cond:{$eq:["$$this.k","DATA.COD"]}}}},0]}})
```

To break this down:

- `op:"update"` - exact match on the `op` field
- `$expr` - use aggregation expressions
- `{$objectToArray:"$$ROOT.command.q"}` - convert the `command.q` subdocument to an array of documents each containing a single key-value pair
- `{$eq:["$$this.k","DATA.COD"]}` - check if the current key name is "DATA.COD"
- `{$filter:{input: ... , cond: ...}}` - eliminate elements from the input array that do not match the condition
- `{$size: ...}` - return the size of the array
- `{$gt:[ ..., 0]}` - determine if the first argument is greater than zero

Summary:

- Convert `q: {"DATA.COD":12, NAME:"PIPPO"}` to `q:[{k:"DATA.DOC", v:12},{k:"NAME",v:"PIPPO"}]`
- eliminate all array elements that do not match `k=="DATA.DOC"`
- Match the document if the array still contains any elements
- repeat for all documents in the collection

Comment: i will try it tomorrow morning. meanwhile i've just found that is not out-of-the-box supported as stated here https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-30575

Comment: Exactly, which is why the above converts the keys to strings for comparison.